# Finding unmatched records in sql with conditions

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have two tables,

System 1 and system 2

System 1 have cloumn a and system 2 has cloumns a b and c

The conditions are that I need to match
The first 6 characters on system 1 Cloumn a to system 2 cloumn a and

Return all the mismatches on system 2

Is there a join for this?

I tried this

Select substring(system1, 1,6) s1
Not exists (select * from system2 s2

Where

S1.A = S2.A)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM system1 t1
LEFT JOIN system2 t2 ON SUBSTRING(t1.a FROM 1 FOR 6) = t2.a
WHERE t2.a IS NULL
```